# bash: how to display the first 10 lines using qstat?

Tags: bash, unix-head

In bash, typing `qstat` will show all the job status.

```
4426868 0.00000 md_0_1     username      hqw   12/31/2017 11:45:25                                   12
4426869 0.00000 md_0_1     username      hqw   12/31/2017 11:45:25                                   12
4426870 0.00000 md_0_1     username      hqw   12/31/2017 11:45:25                                   12
```

......

As I have hundreds of jobs, can I only show the first 10 jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't have `qstat` command in my system so couldn't test.
Try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
qstat | head -10
```

Comment: yes! but it shows the first 8, not the first 10 though. But thank you very much!

Comment: @lanselibai, it worked for me on a test file, are you sure you not having empty lines or so in your output?

Comment: no worries, there is always 2 difference, I just need to use 12 to show the 10 lines